# Avoid flashing when update state in material ui

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm using material ui's dialog in react.js

But I have a question that I'm using ternary to return different dialog based on the state.

Then I realized there'll be a short flashing between the state changed.

I've stuck in here for a long time, hope someone can help me with this.

Here's the code and the [sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/snowy-cherry-6t6bok?file=/demo.tsx)

```
import * as React from "react";
import Button from "@mui/material/Button";
import Dialog from "@mui/material/Dialog";
import DialogActions from "@mui/material/DialogActions";
import DialogContent from "@mui/material/DialogContent";
import DialogContentText from "@mui/material/DialogContentText";
import DialogTitle from "@mui/material/DialogTitle";

export default function AlertDialog() {
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
  const [send, setSend] = React.useState(false);

  const handleClickOpen = () => {
    setOpen(true);
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };

  return send ? (
    <div>
      <Button variant="outlined" onClick={handleClickOpen}>
        Open alert dialog
      </Button>
      <Dialog
        open={open}
        onClose={handleClose}
        aria-labelledby="alert-dialog-title"
        aria-describedby="alert-dialog-description"
      >
        <DialogTitle id="alert-dialog-title">
          {"Use Google's location service?"}
        </DialogTitle>
        <DialogContent>
          <DialogContentText id="alert-dialog-description">
            Some thing went wrong.
          </DialogContentText>
        </DialogContent>
        <DialogActions>
          <Button onClick={handleClose}>Disagree</Button>
          <Button
            onClick={() => {
              handleClose();
              setSend(!send);
            }}
            autoFocus
          >
            Agree
          </Button>
        </DialogActions>
      </Dialog>
    </div>
  ) : (
    <div>
      <Button variant="outlined" onClick={handleClickOpen}>
        Open alert dialog
      </Button>
      <Dialog
        open={open}
        onClose={handleClose}
        aria-labelledby="alert-dialog-title"
        aria-describedby="alert-dialog-description"
      >
        <DialogTitle id="alert-dialog-title">
          {"Use Google's location service?"}
        </DialogTitle>
        <DialogContent>
          <DialogContentText id="alert-dialog-description">
            Let Google help apps determine location. This means sending
            anonymous location data to Google, even when no apps are running.
          </DialogContentText>
        </DialogContent>
        <DialogActions>
          <Button onClick={handleClose}>Disagree</Button>
          <Button
            onClick={() => {
              handleClose();
              setSend(!send);
            }}
            autoFocus
          >
            Agree
          </Button>
        </DialogActions>
      </Dialog>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem is both dialogs are referred to as the same component without `key`, so in every re-rendering, it considers both dialogs are using the same state for display (but actually, they are not).

The fix can be adding a `key` prop to each dialog differently which would help to make them unique in re-renderings.

```
import * as React from "react";
import Button from "@mui/material/Button";
import Dialog from "@mui/material/Dialog";
import DialogActions from "@mui/material/DialogActions";
import DialogContent from "@mui/material/DialogContent";
import DialogContentText from "@mui/material/DialogContentText";
import DialogTitle from "@mui/material/DialogTitle";

export default function AlertDialog() {
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
  const [send, setSend] = React.useState(false);

  const handleClickOpen = () => {
    setOpen(true);
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };

  return send ? (
    <div>
      <Button variant="outlined" onClick={handleClickOpen}>
        Open alert dialog
      </Button>
      <Dialog
        key="error-dialog"
        open={open}
        onClose={handleClose}
        aria-labelledby="alert-dialog-title"
        aria-describedby="alert-dialog-description"
      >
        <DialogTitle id="alert-dialog-title">
          {"Use Google's location service?"}
        </DialogTitle>
        <DialogContent>
          <DialogContentText id="alert-dialog-description">
            Some thing went wrong.
          </DialogContentText>
        </DialogContent>
        <DialogActions>
          <Button onClick={handleClose}>Disagree</Button>
          <Button
            onClick={() => {
              handleClose();
              setSend(!send);
            }}
            autoFocus
          >
            Agree
          </Button>
        </DialogActions>
      </Dialog>
    </div>
  ) : (
    <div>
      <Button variant="outlined" onClick={handleClickOpen}>
        Open alert dialog
      </Button>
      <Dialog
        key="location-dialog"
        open={open}
        onClose={handleClose}
        aria-labelledby="alert-dialog-title"
        aria-describedby="alert-dialog-description"
      >
        <DialogTitle id="alert-dialog-title">
          {"Use Google's location service?"}
        </DialogTitle>
        <DialogContent>
          <DialogContentText id="alert-dialog-description">
            Let Google help apps determine location. This means sending
            anonymous location data to Google, even when no apps are running.
          </DialogContentText>
        </DialogContent>
        <DialogActions>
          <Button onClick={handleClose}>Disagree</Button>
          <Button
            onClick={() => {
              handleClose();
              setSend(!send);
            }}
            autoFocus
          >
            Agree
          </Button>
        </DialogActions>
      </Dialog>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[The sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-sid-xc2rv1?file=/demo.tsx:0-2604)